# SICP lisp 'if' conditional expression explanation

Tags: if-statement, scheme, lisp, conditional-statements, sicp

I'm working through SICP and have gotten to the part about the square root code. I understood that 'if' statements could only be followed by single expressions. However, in the code,

```
(define (sqrt-iter guess x)
    (if (good-enough? guess x)
    guess
    (sqrt-iter (improve guess x)
               x)))
```

I don't understand how the 3rd, 4th, and 5th lines are valid when the 'guess' and 'x' have already been stated as the consequent expressions for 'if'.

Comment: No, `if` accepts three s-expressions as arguments. `(good-enough? guess x)` is a single s-expression. `guess` is the second and `(square-iter ...)` is the third.

Answer (score 6):

In *some* Scheme interpreters an `if` special form can be followed by one or two expressions after the condition, in others (for example: Racket) the condition must be followed by exactly two expressions. But in your code there are two expressions after the condition! it's more of an indentation problem, see:

```
(define (sqrt-iter guess x)
  (if (good-enough? guess x)       ; condition
      guess                        ; first expression  (consequent)
      (sqrt-iter (improve guess x) ; second expression (alternative)
                 x)))
```

To clarify: `guess` and `x` are *not* the consequent and alternative of the condition, they are the arguments for the `good-enough?` procedure in the expression `(good-enough? guess x)`, which is just the condition part. Remember that the general structure of an `if` expression looks like this:

```
(if <condition>
    <consequent>
    <alternative>)
```

Where each part is an expression. For further details please refer to the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html).

Comment: Dear drive-by downvoter: care to comment? any suggestions on how to correct or improve my answer?

Answer (score 3):

`guess` and `x` are arguments to the `good-enough?` predicate, "`if`" is selecting between the following `guess` and `(sqrt-iter ...)` expressions.

Answer (score 1):

No, In scheme language, 'if' statements could followed by two or three expressions, not only one.

```
(if test-exp then-exp else-exp)
```

Even in some implement of scheme interpreter，'if' statements MUST followed by three expressions, 'else-exp' can not be ommitted.

More details read:
http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps112/Spring03/languages/scheme/SchemeTutorialA.html#condexp